# Textures on animated boolean moves with object

Tags: animation, texturing, materials, modifiers, uv

I want to ask you about the settings for a texture in an animation I'm making.

It is just a cylinder going through a cube and making a hole in it. It is working with a boolean  modifier set in difference mode, but the hole gets the texture of the boolean and moves with the cylinder. I need the texture stay fixed when the cylinder moves. I have tried all the configurations and can't find a way.

Please help!!

Comment: Can you post the Blend file. I haven't done that kind of animation so I'll try to figure out the problem.

You can post files at "http://www.pasteall.org/blend/"

Comment: Hi Ray, thanks for your answer. You can download de .blend file and a video of the animation. It is a perforation in rock soil, and the idea is that the material inside of the perforation tube stay fixed with the soil (don't move with the hole). LINKS: .blend: http://www.mediafire.com/download/a7otv8c220bb40d/Perforation.blend  Video: http://www.mediafire.com/watch/sc0019vfec1ogp8/perforation0001-0081.avi The file was worked in blender 2.69 because of a bug I find in the boolean modifier in the latests versions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, my error here is the .blend link again.. http://www.mediafire.com/download/c3hwq5boj5zkh5w/Perforation.blend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First start by making the texture "stay fixed" on the cylinder.  You can probably accomplish this by making a longer immobile cylinder which is then boolean intersected with a moving cube.  Then use that composite object to make the hole in the cube.

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31488

The sample blend illustrates this.

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Booleans#Materials documents that any new faces created in the process use the first material slot in the object hosting the modifier.  You will notice the cube has two materials.

You will notice that I have hide_render=True (the camera icon is greyed out in the outliner) for the drill objects.

The immobile drill cylinder has a UV map I created by marking seams and unwrapping with a cylindrical projection.

Comment: Please add some more details on how to do this.

Comment: Hi Mutant Bob, thanks for your answer. there is no second material in the stack. The file you send me looks like you can get the texture fixed, but I can't understand how.. I'm going to check the file in detail. My animation is a perforation in rock soil, and the idea is the material inside of the perforation tube stay fixed with the soil (don't move with the hole). LINKS: .blend: http://www.mediafire.com/download/c3hwq5boj5zkh5w/Perforation.blend Video: mediafire.com/watch/sc0019vfec1ogp8/perforation0001-0081.avi Thank you!

Comment: "You can probably accomplish this by making a longer immobile cylinder which is then boolean intersected with a moving cube. Then use that composite object to make the hole in the cube."